# remove new lines

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, perl

My input is a csv file like this:

```
10,"Special Projects,bangaram",0,,0
10,"Statutory/ Internal Audit , MO reporting (incl Excel Spreadsheet uploadation)
",     bangaram,0,,0
10,"Complience with SVCCL",     bangaram,       0,,     0
10,     "Release of incentives / commission to all channel partners.
",      bangaram,       0,,     0
10,"Timely processing of sales orders to channel partners",     bangaram,       0,,     0
10,"    Balance sheet Reviwe", bangaram,        0,,     0
10,"    Ensuring Critical Reconciliation on monthly basis. (IN-GL)",    bangaram,       0,,     0
10,     "Timely & accurate closure of Accounts.
",      bangaram,       0,,     0
11,"    Opex Spend on communication activites", bangaram,       0,,     0
11,"    Opex Spend on communication activites", bangaram        ,0,,    0
```

I need to get output like this:

```
10,"Special Projects,bangaram",0,,0
10,"Statutory/ Internal Audit , MO reporting (incl Excel Spreadsheet uploadation)",     bangaram,0,,0
10,"Complience with SVCCL",     bangaram,       0,,     0
10,     "Release of incentives / commission to all channel partners.",      bangaram,       0,,     0
10,"Timely processing of sales orders to channel partners",     bangaram,       0,,     0
10,"    Balance sheet Reviwe", bangaram,        0,,     0
10,"    Ensuring Critical Reconciliation on monthly basis. (IN-GL)",    bangaram,       0,,     0
10,     "Timely & accurate closure of Accounts.",      bangaram,       0,,     0
11,"    Opex Spend on communication activites", bangaram,       0,,     0
11,"    Opex Spend on communication activites", bangaram        ,0,,    0
```

Where ever new line is der that will be delete and then add to previous line.
Please write shell script regarding this.

Comment: You should never do generic CSV parsing using shell script or using regex. Use something like Python/Perl with a proper CVS parsing module that takes care of escaped quotes, semi-colons instead of comma's, etc. instead.

Comment: 'Where ever new line is der that will be delete', what does this mean?

Comment: Are you sure there are no escaped double quotes " in any of the of the lines?  The line with text `Release of incentives` would normally be interpreted in an CSV file to be a string that starts with a few spaces and includes a double quote character in the middle of string.

Comment: dont warry about spaces, logic is every row should be 5 comma's if not just concatenate to next line.. that's it.. plz tel me..

Comment: @suneelbabu.etl you should absolutely worry about the spaces: `1,"abc",` in CSV is something completely different from `1, "abc",` as in the second (assuming `,` as separator) the `"` is part of the text. So please correct your example

Comment: @suneelbabu.etl You should update/sanitize your input example,  Excel will read that in as 10 lines, but two of them have a string starting with `,bangaram` in the first field.

Comment: No Anthon that spaces i can delete yar using another tool.. but i want to delete the newlines only..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the spaces between the `,` and `"` are typos (if not then the `"` is embedded in a string starting with a space character and your CVS file non-standard), you can do the following in Python:

```
import sys
import csv

out = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
with open(sys.argv[1]) as csv_file:
    for line in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"'):
        out.writerow([x.replace('\n', '') for x in line])
```

This will also properly handle double quotes when they occur within a double quoted string such as  `" abc""def "` which will get you the string `abc"def`

Please note that the Python csv module by default removes redundant quotes from the output. The last line e.g. will be

```
11,    Opex Spend on communication activites, bangaram        ,0,,    0
```

as in a proper CSV file no quotes are necessary around the second element (it does not contain the quoting character nor does it contain a newline).

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your example is hard to understand and you really should use a proper parser. For the specific example you have shown, this  will work but it will break on more complex cases, it just removes all newlines (`\n`) that come before a `"`:

```
perl -000pe 's/\n"/"/g' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk -vRS=\" 'NR%2 == 0 {gsub("\n","")}; {ORS=RT; print}'
```